# Laravel image uploading on localhost, strage path

Tags: laravel

I have a project witch i'm working on and facing a small problem. I will share below some of my code to let you guys know where i'm.

This is my my method on the **Controller**:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
   $image = $request->file('image');
   $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   Image::make($image)->resize(200, 200)->save( public_path('/images/' . $filename ) );

   $editors->image = $filename;
}
```

This is my input on the **view**:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Editor avatar</label>
     <input type="file" name="image">
</div>
```

When i submit the form everything is ok even without required error messages. 
But when i go to my folder inside **public/images** nothings is there.

And if i go to my db i receive this path for the image:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\php840D.tmp

What might be the problem?

Comment: Check folder rights...

Comment: Hello, komal thanks for your response but i'm using xampp on windows and all the permissions are in order.

Comment: Ok.. Share your form code

Comment: Where are you setting the file path to save in the database?  That looks like a temp location for file uploads or something.

Comment: I'm saving in the database only the file name nothing more. But when i open my db i receive that path

Answer (score 0):

Check your upload folder(i.e. 'images') permission. It should be having 775 permission.

Other then this, you code is fine.

**NOTE:** This should give both the apache and FTP users the ability to write to the files in the folder but keep everyone else from modifying them.

**EDIT:**

Check below points:

> 1. You don't have access to view the file.
> 2. Use chmod("/path/to/file.ext", 0755); to add view rights for the ftp user.
> 3. You moved the file to an location that doesn't store the file. /dev/null
> 4. You're looking in the wrong folder. Did you use a full path?

The file is removed shortly after the move.

**NOTE:** If you working on remote server then uploaded file probably they were still in the server queue so you need to refresh and check it.

Comment: It is not that the problem.

Comment: No worries! Can you please use `if (!$image->move($destinationPathImg, $image->getClientOriginalName())) {
    return 'Error saving the file.';
}` piece of code for checking purpose. Let me know this code print as expect OR not?

Comment: No i still receive the Success page and not what is should show on return.

Comment: You means that image moved successfully at `$destinationPathImg` path ?

Comment: it seams so, but when i go to the folder there is nothing there ?

Comment: I'm working locally but i will try to put my project live maybe it is for real e permission problem, and i will let you know thanks

Comment: Hmmm... It's good option. But you already commented me that "It is not that the problem"

Comment: The permissions locally are ok, but maybe is a glitch or something, im testing live also maybe im missing something

Comment: Ok, Let me know if you need any help from me...Glad to help you!

Comment: Hey still the same problem even on live server, into db i have this path again /tmp/phppL2TAK

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $upload_success = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
  $image = Image::make("uploads/$filename")->resize(200, 200)->save();
  if( $upload_success ) {
    $editors->image = $filename;
  }
  else
  {
    $editors->image = 'unknown.png';
  }   
}
```

Comment: I tried but still the same. I don't know what might be the problem.

Comment: Create uploads folder in public folder

Comment: I have created that folder, but still it dosent work.

Comment: Your form <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: important to add enctype when you upload file

Comment: I have added Files = > true

Comment: @Komal: OP already said that he/she stored image path into db.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem even on live server, what might be the problem